# mercurial hgweb.config do not find repositories, path issue

Tags: mercurial, hgweb

I have a repository set up on an apache web server using the hgweb.cgi script declared in my apache2.conf file as following:

```
ScriptAlias /hgp "/var/www/hgrepublic/hgweb.cgi"
```

In my hgweb.cgi script, if I set the config variable as the path to my repository:

```
config = "/var/www/hgrepublic/fakecake"
```

it works and I see the history of my repository at http://localhost/hgp

Now if I want to use the hgweb.config file, I set the config variable in the hgweb.cgi script like:

```
config = "hgweb.config"
```

whatever the paths I try to use in config file, I cannot see my repository in the web interface (empty repository index). Here are a few examples I tried with absolute and relative paths

```
[paths]
/ = /var/www/hgrepublic/**
fakecake = /fakecake
fakecake = /var/www/hgrepublic/fakecake
```

Any idea to help me make it work with the config file? (I would like to have several repositories declared in the config file)

Note: hgweb cgi and config files are in the /var/www/hgrepublic/ folder as well as the fakecake repository folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my own question by looking at the source.

I used a dict in the hgweb.cgi file to pass the different repositories I want to show:

```
config = {'repo1' : '/path/to/repo1', 'repo2' : '/path/to/repo2'}
```

It works like this, so I think that there might be a parsing problem in hgweb.config file for [paths] section?

Answer (score 0):

The `[paths]` section converts the URL to the repository path.  Try:

hgweb.config

```
[paths]
/hpg/fakecake = /var/www/hgrepublic/fakecake
/hpg/repo2 = /var/www/hgrepublic/repo2
```

hgweb.cgi

```
config = "hgweb.cgi"  # or /path/to/hgweb.cgi if not in cwd
```